# Как сделать layout прозрачным?

Tags: android, xml

Можно ли как-то сделать layout прозрачным? Я не могу заменить layout каким-то другим элементом, так как использую DataBinding, свойств чтобы поменять background у него нет, стили или темы назначить тоже нельзя, а его дефолтный background белый. Как я могу изменить его цвет на подходящий? (android:background и background я пробовал, app:background тоже нету, layout именно `<layout/>`, не какой-то другой)

P.S: У меня нет проблемы с прозрачным цветом, проблема в том, что я не могу изменить background layout'a, я не могу просто перекрыть другим лейаутом с цветом фона приложения, так как весь лейаут может становится полупрозрачным, и не изменяя background корневого layout'a я получу не полупрозрачный элемент, а полупрозрачный элемент на белом фоне

Comment: Зачем вам делать layout прозрачным?

Comment: @RhaegarTargaryen, он белый, а приложение в темной теме

Comment: Поменяй в файле манифеста тему на темную и все. Вопрос задан некорректно, поэтому тебе не дали исчерпывающего ответа)

Comment: @RhaegarTargaryen, у меня свои цвета и просто сменой темы вряд-ли получится что-то изменить, я уже пробовал менять цвета в стандартной теме, темная - та же тема с другими цветами, мне не только из-за того как смотрится на фоне нужно это сделать, дело в том что другой лейаут тоже должен быть прозрачным, короче говоря кое-что должно становится полупрозрачным, но из-за того что я не могу изменить этот корневой элемент у меня к прозрачности примешивается белый цвет, я думаю все-таки должен быть способ изменить background этого лейаута и по-моему вопрос как раз задан корректно, из моего вопроса

Comment: понятно в чем мне нужна помощь

Comment: как раз из-за того что мне нужно делать элемент прозрачным, мне нужно найти возможность делать layout прозрачным, так бы я просто закрыл layout любым другим с измененным background'ом, но это не решит второй главной проблемы

Answer (score 2):

Добавь вот этот в background -

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

Comment: Никак, нету свойства background у именно layout, не LinearLayout и не Constraint Layout и да android:background тоже не работает: Resource compilation failed

Answer (score 0):

Из чего тут выросла проблема? =)
Представьте что вы работаете без DataBinding, сверстайте ваш экран как хотите. Можете сделать корневым лайаутом какой угодно: Relative, Constraint, Linear или все что вам нравится. Повесьте корневому лайауту, как выше отметил @Bad Broker

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

Ну а теперь оборачивайте все это в  для DataBinding, добавляйте нужные импорты, переменные и будет вам счастье)

В качестве примера:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<data>

</data>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    tools:context=".ui.biometry.BiometryActivity">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/biometry_host"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/biometry_graph"
        />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: Дело в том что если так сделать, то лэйаут не будет прозрачным, это видно на темном фоне, на самом деле он просто белый, у меня нет проблем с прозрачным цветом, проблема в том что я не могу его задать, так как у layout нет свойств для изменения background'a